# Is it possible to add an image to tkinter combobox?

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox, tkinter-canvas

Is it possible to add an image to a combobox in tkinter?
I tried the following, but I already expected it to not work.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *
# Creating tkinter window
window = tk.Tk()
window.title('Combobox')
window.geometry('1440x900')
main_canvas = Canvas(
    window,
    bg = "#FFFFFF",
    height = 900,
    width = 1440,
    bd = 0,
    highlightthickness = 0,
    relief = "ridge"
)
main_canvas.place(x = 0, y = 0)

main_button_image_1 = PhotoImage(
    file="button_1.png")

n = tk.StringVar()
monthchoosen = ttk.Combobox(window, width = 27, textvariable = n, image=main_button_image_1)
  
# Adding combobox drop down list
monthchoosen['values'] = ('new')

monthchoosen.place(
    x=10.0,
    y=826.0,
    width=55.0,
    height=55.0
)
monthchoosen.current(0)
window.mainloop()
```

Basically I want to make the combobox look a bit better and the easiest way would be to design an image and add it to the combobox.

PS:
I just copied real quick a few thinks, so please don't mind the variable names.

Comment: why do you import from `tkinter` **3 times**? import only what you need (don't use `*` when importing, you don't know the package well enough, and if you did, then you would know not to use `*`) Also it is very possible to create a custom Combobox for images, tho you will need to show your efforts on that one, there however is no built-in method as stated in answer below

Comment: yea 2 of them are pretty useless, but I just copied some things from a website to test it real quick, so I didnt really mind them. Of course in my main program I dont import something twice

Comment: Actually, two of them are critical, the third is useless.

Comment: Dont I import everything of tkinter when using '*' ?

Comment: But anyways I think its pretty pointless to discuss about that, doesn't help with the problem

Comment: You import everything from the package, meaning from the __init__.py file, modules such as ttk in that package are not imported, because that is a module or another package

Answer (score 1):

No, the ttk.Combobox widget does not support images.

Comment: @the_guy71639 you can still make a custom combobox to support images if you really need

Comment: @Matiiss: yes, of course. That wasn't the question. The question was whether the standard combobox can use images.

Comment: Oh thats sounds interesting, is there any good source you know, where I can read about custom comboboxes?